# Updating sync changes in client

Tags: gun

I've got Gun synchronizing across a couple of clients. On one I'm subscribing to the data using **map().on()**. On the other I delete an item using **map().unset()**. My question, when I delete an item the changes pops up on the other client as *null* - I don't seem to have any other information. Is it possible then to keep my client in-sync with changes i.e. in this case remove the item from the list I am showing on the screen? I don't know which item null is referencing to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@peter great question! Two things:

1. As a background on what the `null` is doing for deleting, you probably already saw https://gun.eco/docs/Delete .
2. To answer your question, `.on` callback has multiple parameters, so `.on(function(data, key` is what you want. Data will be `null` and you know which item it was based on the `key`. Check out the rest of the [API here](https://gun.eco/docs/API#on)!

   > Pro tip: If `gun.get('list').map().on((data, key) => ...)` grabs all the items then `gun.get('list').get(key).on(data => ...)` is how to grab only that one item from the table!